My URL Application is redirecting to home when query string is applied
I deployed my laravel application in Red Hat Server with NGINX engine for pass proxy params from AWS Load Balancer. I use laravel livewire table plugin for show the data. My problem is when i click filter in table component, the url is change (ex: example.com/menu/submenu -> example.com/?filter=true)
This is my nginx config
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   300;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout          600;
    proxy_read_timeout          600;
    send_timeout                600;

    client_max_body_size 200M;
    #more_clear_headers Server;
    server_tokens off;
    fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}

server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    listen [::]:8080 default_server;
    server_name localhost;

    root         /var/www/example/public;
    index        index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/testing-error.log;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload' always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; font-src * data:;img-src * data:; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.gstatic.com; style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'self' https//*.googleapis.com";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin";
    add_header Permissions-Policy "geolocation=(self),midi=(),sync-xhr=(),microphone=(),camera=(),magnetometer=(),gyroscope=(),fullscreen=(self),payment=()";
    add_header Feature-Policy "geolocation 'self';midi 'none';sync-xhr 'none';microphone 'none';camera 'none';magnetometer 'none';gyroscope 'none';fullscreen 'self';payment 'none';";

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/javascript;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        #include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.htaccess {
        deny  all;
    }

    location ~ /\web.config {
        deny  all;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;

#    listen       443;

    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Request-Uri $request_uri;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_proxy.log;

}

I want when i applied filter from tabel the url didn't changed.

It's more related to laravel routes not nginx. Try to provide laravel code
